# Call to a member function find() on a non-object str_get_html

Tags: simple-html-dom

Есть некая переменная `$html`, полученная через curl (все работает). Дальше хочу получить `div` c классом `partscontrol`:

```
$simpleHTML = new SimpleHTMLDOM;
$div=$simpleHTML->str_get_html($html);
$results=$div->find('.partscontrol');
```

но `$results` возвращает пустой массив. Если искать просто `<div>` или `<a>` и т.д., то все работает. В чем загвоздка? Такие варианты как `('.partscontrol',0)`,`('div.partscontrol',0)`,`('div.partscontrol')`,`('div.partscontrol',0)`-результат тот же.

Comment: $results=$div->find('.partscontrol');-не работает вообще($results возвращает пустой масив),$results=$div->find('div')-все нормально.В чем проблема?Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо суть по-другому указывать, что ищете по классу.

```
$results=$div->find('div[class=partscontrol]');
```

или иногда еще вот это сработать может

```
$results=$div->find('div[class="partscontrol"]');
```

Comment: к сожалению и эти варианты возвращают пустую строку

Comment: А вы уверены, что `$div` у Вас не пустой? Если `curl` выдал вам невалидный `html`, то `str_get_html()` может не сработать.

Comment: уверен,я в первую очередь проверил.Говорю если искать просто 'div',то все есть,но если по класу то пустой результат)

Comment: или невалидный html вы имеете в виду что то другое?